# I want to make validations into my dynamic tabs form using reactive form approach

Tags: angular, validation, tabs, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which has six tabs. I want separate validations on each tab. let's say if I'm on tab 1 then it should validate only tab 1 data fields. and then if i'm switching to tab 2 then tab 1 data fields validations should be gone and it should show me only tab 2 validations. Note - I have some common fields too in my form. lets say first name is there in all tabs.[image][image]

> HTML File

```
<div class="add-person-list-page">
<h2 class="text-muted">Add Persons</h2>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="addPerson" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body switch-field">
                    <small class="form-text text-muted mb-3">Select role to show minimum mandatory fields.</small>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="1"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Pax</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="2"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Pilot</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="3"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Crew</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="4"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Emerg</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="5"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Op/Ow</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="personRoleType"
                        (change)="onChangeRole(roleType)" [(ngModel)]="roleType" [value]="6"
                        formControlName="personRoleType">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Any</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    GENERAL
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"
                            formControlName="firstName"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 5">
                        <label>Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Middle Name"
                            formControlName="middleName"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.middleName.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.middleName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.middleName.errors.required">Middle Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name"
                            formControlName="lastName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body switch-field text-center" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="gender" name="gender"
                            value="male">
                        <label class="form-check-label gender"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="gender" name="gender"
                            value="female">
                        <label class="form-check-label gender"><i class="fa fa-female"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.gender.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.gender.errors.required">Gender is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    BIRTH DETAILS
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Birth Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Birth Date" bsDatepicker
                            formControlName="birthDate"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthDate.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthDate.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthDate.errors.required">Birth Date is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType === 6">
                        <label>Birth City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Birth City"
                            formControlName="birthCity"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthCity.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthCity.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthCity.errors.required">Birth City is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType === 6">
                        <label>Birth State</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Birth State"
                            formControlName="birthState"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthState.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthState.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthState.errors.required">Birth State is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType === 6">
                        <label>Birth Country</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="birthCountry"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthCountry.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Birth Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthCountry.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthCountry.errors.required">Birth Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Residence</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="birthResidence"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthResidence.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Residence Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthResidence.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthResidence.errors.required">Residence Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Citizenship</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="birthCitizenship"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthCitizenship.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Citizenship Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.birthCitizenship.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.birthCitizenship.errors.required">Select Citizenship is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="roleType !== 1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    PERMANENT ADDRESS
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4">
                        <label>Street</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Street Address"
                            formControlName="paStreet" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paStreet.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paStreet.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paStreet.errors.required">Street Address is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4">
                        <label>City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" formControlName="paCity"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paCity.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paCity.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paCity.errors.required">City is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
                        <label>State</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter State" formControlName="paState"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paState.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paState.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paState.errors.required">State is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
                        <label>Postal Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Postal Code"
                            formControlName="paPostalCode"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paPostalCode.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paPostalCode.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paPostalCode.errors.required">Postal Code is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="paCountry"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paCountry.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paCountry.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paCountry.errors.required">Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 1 && roleType !== 3">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                            formControlName="paPhone" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paPhone.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paPhone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paPhone.errors.required">Phone Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType === 6 && roleType !== 5">
                        <label>Fax</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fax Number"
                            formControlName="paFax" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paFax.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paFax.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paFax.errors.required">Fax Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roleType !== 4">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="paEmail"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.paEmail.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.paEmail.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.paEmail.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="roleType !== 4 && roleType !== 5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    PRIMARY DOCUMENT
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Document</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="primaryDocument"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.primaryDocument.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Document</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.primaryDocument.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.primaryDocument.errors.required">Document is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Number"
                            formControlName="primaryDocumentNumber"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.primaryDocumentNumber.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.primaryDocumentNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.primaryDocumentNumber.errors.required">ID Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Issued by</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="primaryDocumentIssuedBy"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.primaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.primaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.primaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors.required">Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Expiration</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Expiration Date" bsDatepicker
                            formControlName="primaryDocumentExp"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.primaryDocumentExp.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.primaryDocumentExp.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.primaryDocumentExp.errors.required">Expiration Date is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="roleType === 6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    SECONDARY DOCUMENT
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Document</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="secondaryDocument"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.secondaryDocument.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Document</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.secondaryDocument.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.secondaryDocument.errors.required">Document is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Number"
                            formControlName="secondaryDocumentNumber"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.secondaryDocumentNumber.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.secondaryDocumentNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.secondaryDocumentNumber.errors.required">ID Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Issued by</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="secondaryDocumentIssuedBy"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.secondaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.secondaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.secondaryDocumentIssuedBy.errors.required">Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Expiration</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Expiration Date" bsDatepicker
                            formControlName="secondaryDocumentExp"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.secondaryDocumentExp.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.secondaryDocumentExp.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.secondaryDocumentExp.errors.required">Expiration Date is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" *ngIf="roleType === 2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    PILOT'S LICENSE
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Document</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="pilotDocument"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.pilotDocument.errors }">
                            <option value="1">Pilot's License</option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pilotDocument.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.pilotDocument.errors.required">Document is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Number"
                            formControlName="pilotDocumentNumber"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.pilotDocumentNumber.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pilotDocumentNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.pilotDocumentNumber.errors.required">ID Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Issued by</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="pilotDocumentIssuedBy"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.pilotDocumentIssuedBy.errors }">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let country of countryArray" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pilotDocumentIssuedBy.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.pilotDocumentIssuedBy.errors.required">Country is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Expiration</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Expiration Date" bsDatepicker
                            formControlName="pilotDocumentExp"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.pilotDocumentExp.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pilotDocumentExp.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.pilotDocumentExp.errors.required">Expiration Date is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit"> Add Person</button>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary float-right" type="button"> Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> ts file

```
export class addPersonComponent implements OnInit {
roleType: number = 1;
addPerson: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
countryArray = [];
Ispax: boolean = false;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private flashPassService: FlashpassService, protected loadingService: LoadingService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.getListofCountry();
}

initForm() {
    this.addPerson = this.formBuilder.group({

        personRoleType: ['1'],
        firstName: [''],
        lastName: [''],
        middleName: [''],
        gender: [''],
        birthDate: [''],
        birthCity: [''],
        birthState: [''],
        birthCountry: [''],
        birthResidence: [''],
        birthCitizenship: [''],
        paStreet: [''],
        paCity: [''],
        paState: [''],
        paPostalCode: [''],
        paCountry: [''],
        paPhone: [''],
        paFax: [''],
        paEmail: [''],
        primaryDocument: [''],
        primaryDocumentNumber: [''],
        primaryDocumentIssuedBy: [''],
        primaryDocumentExp: [''],
        secondaryDocument: [''],
        secondaryDocumentNumber: [''],
        secondaryDocumentIssuedBy: [''],
        secondaryDocumentExp: [''],
        pilotDocument: [''],
        pilotDocumentNumber: [''],
        pilotDocumentIssuedBy: [''],
        pilotDocumentExp: [''],
    });
}

// initialize form instance.
get f() { return this.addPerson.controls; }

// Signup form submit function.
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.addPerson.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    // this.router.navigate(['/companies']);
}

getListofCountry() {
    this.loadingService.startLoading();
    this.flashPassService.getCountryList().subscribe(data => {
        this.countryArray = Object.assign([], data);
        this.loadingService.endLoading();
    });
}

onChangeRole(type) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this.f.<yourFormControlName>.setValidators([yourValidator])` method on your tab change event. Manually set validations to your form fields or you can also set custom errors `this.f.<yourFormControlName>.setErrors({yourCustomError});`

Comment: Hello I have used above methods but doesn't work. it do sets an error but when I change tab the error still appers there. I want to clear them. so can you please provide more details about this.

Comment: On tab change event based on the requirement, you should set and remove the validations, to set the above code will work but to remove just pass the empty array and object to setValidators and setErrors respective. So you have to do it individually to each form field on the respective tab in tab change event. Also after setting validations or erros there is chance they might not get updated yet times so you have to use .updateValueAndValidity(); method to those fields again to ensure they are upto date with your changes.

Comment: I have done it through the combinations of these two methods 1.  this.f.<yourFormControlName>.setErrors({yourCustomError}); and
2.  this.f.<yourFormControlName>.reset("");
@kishore thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @PoojanPandya you are welcome, if you think it helped, can you mark the answer as correct.